# Change compiler to XeLeTax in overleaf but still failed

Tags: latex

I used the command from

[enter link description here](https://github.com/deedy/Deedy-Resume/blob/master/OpenFonts/deedy-resume-openfont.cls)

and since it showed that

> `" THIS TEMPLATE NEEDS TO BE COMPILED WITH XeLaTeX`

So I changed my compiler to "LuaLaTex" in my Overleaf account,

but still failed to reconcile.

Anyone has the same questions using Overleaf Resume Template?

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select XeLaTeX as compiler, not LuaLaTeX, as you wrote:

> ```
> " THIS TEMPLATE NEEDS TO BE COMPILED WITH XeLaTeX
> ```

XeLaTex and LuaLateX are different things. You can select XeLaTeX as compiler in overleaf in the same menu you selected LuaLaTeX:

[image]